# Passar valores de uma GridView para banco de dados

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, winforms, microsoft-access

Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar os valores de uma gridview no windowsform e passar para meu banco de dados no Access.

Comment: Poste algum código para que seja mais fácil para os membros ajuda-lo

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Você poderá obter respostas melhores e mais rápidas se der uma olhada em [Como fazer uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e/ou faça o [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: O correto seria você começar por um tutorial, como este: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AE-PS6-sL7U